How do you migate a maven repo hosted on Azure DevOps?
I want to move away from Azure DevOps in favor of other providers, the only problem is that I have a bunch of artifacts on the maven packages and I need them migrated too.
My new provider also offers maven repositories, but there are 1000+ versions of the artifacts in the original one. Is there any easy way of moving all the content of an azure repository to another?
I'm ok keeping just the most recent version of each artifact, but I need all of them.
mvnfeed-cli looked like a good solution, but it's no longer maintained and impossible to install.

Hi, what is your new provider? Another product or Azure Artifacts of another organization?
